# Join first n elements of an m sized array

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

given: `$array = ("a0", "a1", "b0", "b1")`

How do I join **only** `array[0]` & `array[1]`; Such that:

> $a = "a0a1"
>    # as if:  >$a = $a[0]$a[1]

Simillarly,
get: `$b = "b0b1"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select the elements in the array, then use the `-join` operator:

```
$array = ("a0", "a1", "b0", "b1")
$a = $array[0..1] -join ''
$b = $array[2..3] -join ''
```

You can use commas to select non-contiguous elements.

```
$array = ("a0", "a1", "b0", "b1")
$c = $array[0,1,3] -join ''
```

If there is some criteria for the elements you want joined, you could group the array then join the groups.

```
# Joins all elements that start with the same character.
$array = ("a0", "a1", "b0", "b1")
$a = $array| group {$_[0]}| foreach {$_.group -join ''}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thankyou.. also is there any way to do this in a single line and pass it to function as: `fn $a $b` ---> `fn $array[0..1] -join '' $array[2..3] -join ''`

Comment: Yes, wrapping something in parentheses will evaluate a statement before it is sent as an argument. In this case: `fn ($array[0..1] -join '') ($array[2..3] -join '')`

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution:

```
$array= ("a1", "a0", "b0", "b1")
$a,$b = &{$ofs='';[string[]]($array[0,1],$array[2,3])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I think it should work:

```
$array | % {
 switch -Regex ($_)
  {
    ('a\d') {$a = "$($a)$($_)"}
    ('b\d') {$b = "$($b)$($_)"}
  }

}
```